# Trigger event in parent page from a page called inside a child iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In `core.php` I have a dinamic table with buttons.

In `iframe.php` I call `core.php` with AJAX, obtaining the content of `core.php` inside a div in this iframe.

In `index.php` I have this iframe. So i can see the content of `core.php`.

core.php

```
<table>
  /* content table with buttons */
</table>
```

iframe.php

```
<script>
      /* AJAX call to core.php in #mydiv*/
</script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

index.php

```
<iframe src="iframe.php"></iframe>
```

If I trigger event on the div inside `iframe.php` to the parent page it works like a charm. But the div is large as table displayed. I want to trigger event only if I click on button of this table, in `core.php`. In other words, I need to bypass iframe.php and call event from core.php in index.php.

It is possible?

If not, how can I solve?

Comment: Somebody can help me?